# Autocorrelation and spectral density in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, correlation

This question is twofold.

We have an LTI system that is a first degree Butterworth LP filter with the power TF

[image]

where `fu = 110Hz` and `f1 = 90Hz`

The input `X(t)` has the autocorrelation: `R_X(\tau) = 5e^{-600|\tau|}`

1) How can I calculate the power spectral density of the output in MATLAB? FFT? How do I represent the autocorrelation as a vector?

2) How can I simulate the system and plot the output in MATLAB?

Comment: http://www.mathworks.se/help/signal/ug/psd-estimate-using-fft.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate autocorrelation using FFT in matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949324/calculate-autocorrelation-using-fft-in-matlab)

Comment: I thought I had posted this in math.stackexhange, oh well.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the Autocorrelation of the output:

```
R_y = xcorr(y); % with Y(f) = X(f).H(f) or y(t) = x(t)*h(t)
```

To calculate the P.S.D of the output:

```
PSD_y = fft (R_y);
```

To reprensent them graphically, you can use `plot`

if you do not have the x(t) or X(f) expressions, you could use this relation:

```
PSD_y (f) = PSD_x (f) . |H(f)|^2  % with PSD_x (f) = fft(R_x);
```

Comment: I have the autocorrelation of X, but I don't know the actual x. How can I do this given the autocorrelation?

Comment: see my updated answer, and let me know if it worked. thx

Comment: you mean `PSD_y = abs(fft(y)).^2` possibly with zero padding `PSD_y = abs(fft(y, 2*length(y))).^2`